# A white screen will appear before loading an image from url into the ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

How to solve this? Is any other component there to use better than an ImageView for showing an image from a server?
**Purpose:** showing an advertisment in my app for 2 sec.
The image loading is worked properly when the interval is set to 3 sec. but I reduced to 2 sec, then it will show a white screen then appear the image.

MainCode for diaply image from url.

```
 Glide.with(this)
                .load(imageUri)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .into(adImage);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LoadToResumeActivity();
                //adImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isAdEnabled = false;
                resume_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: show errror or placeholder image till image is uploaded

Comment: when we set a placeholder image, it will also show for a while before showing the exact image right? this may make confuse to the user right?

Comment: for general purpose place holder is best idea, but if you want alternative than use thumbnail until  main image load

Comment: You can show the progress bar until image loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need delayed `Handler`, just put delayed code in `onResourceReady` of `Glide`. It's not guaranteed that every time your image will load within 2 seconds so best practices is, visible view only when image loaded.

Java code

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(imageUri)
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false; // important to return false so the error placeholder can be placed
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(adImage);
```

Kotlin Code

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load(imageUri)
        .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
          override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {

            return false
          }

          override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {

            return false
          }
        })
        .apply(RequestOptions()
                .dontTransform()
                .centerCrop()
        .into(adImage)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Its kotlin code right?? Do you know how to implement this in java?

Comment: here is official [docs](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library#loading-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever UI is updated by itself or network call best way to show place holder or progress bar until network call successful. For more about place holder have look [this.](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to show place holder for image loading.

```
Glide.with(this).load(photoToLoad.getPath()).placeholder(imageView.getDrawable()).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Is this avoid the white screen?